# Return value between 0 and 255 indicating shade of image at specified location

Tags: processing

I have a monochrome (black and white) image that I am trying to extract a value between 0 and 255 indicating the shade of the pixel, with 0 being black and 255 being white. I import the image as follows:

```
PImage img;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);
  img = loadImage("myimage.jpg");
  x_location = 50;
  y_location = 230;
  // add code to extract shade from img here
}
```

I am trying to use `get()` to extract the shade. Unfortunately, when I try to use `img.get(x_location, y_location)` it returns a very large negative number (on the order of -1000000). Is there a way to ensure that `get()` returns some normalized (understandable) value?

Comment: I'm going to guess you're using [PImage 3](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_get_.html) (you didn't say). The docs say that "The numbers returned are scaled according to the current color ranges". Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, I believe it’s PImage 3. I suppose that may be the issue; the problem is I don’t know what the current color ranges are or how to retrieve them. It would be useful to know those because then I could just normalize the output myself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is very interesting. Here's some skeleton code which will help you get what you want:

```
PImage img;
color currentColor;

void setup() {
  size(656, 354);
  currentColor = color(0);
  img = loadImage("bean.jpeg");
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  image(img, 0, 0);
  
  fill(currentColor);
  stroke(200);
  strokeWeight(2);
  ellipse(30, 30, 40, 40);
  fill(0);
  text("A  " + alpha(currentColor), 10, 65);
  text("R  " + red(currentColor), 10, 75);
  text("G  " + green(currentColor), 10, 85);
  text("B  " + blue(currentColor), 10, 95);
}

void mouseClicked() {
  currentColor = img.get(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Picking colors!]

The magic here is to know that you can extract the ARGB info which are part of the color. Yet, I also wondered why it was a negative number. [Here's why](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/8086/what-is-a-color-in-processing) (emphasis mine):

> Colors, in Processing, are stored actually in simple Java ints, 32-bit
> values. The color pseudo-type is actually replaced by Processing with
> int when generating Java code before compilation.
>
> **This type has a width of 32 bits, which is perfect as we can put 4
> channels of 8 bits each inside.** 8 bits allow a range of of values from
> 0 to 255 (included). The 4 channels are alpha (opacity), red, green,
> blue, the whole being often abbreviated as ARGB.
>
> Low value of color channel means "low intensity", darkness. High value
> means "high intensity", lightness. So if all channels are 0, we have
> black; if they are all at 255, we have white. Alpha channel is
> different: 0 means low opacity, fully transparent, while 255 means
> high opacity, normal opaque color.
>
> In Java, numbers are always signed. In computing, negative numbers are
> marked by setting the highest bit to 1. **So, opaque colors, the most
> common kind, the default if no opacity is given, is 0xFF = 255, the
> high bit is set to 1, the color value is negative.** Hence the answer to
> the first question...
>
> **The strange values are the result of combining all the values of the
> channels.** Let's take a simple yellowish color. Alpha is 255 (opaque),
> red is 250, green is 230 and blue is, say, 20. These values are 0xFF,
> 0xFA, 0xE6 and 0x14. Combined to make an int, it gives 0xFFFAE614, ie.
> -334316. Hence a strange number, not very easy to decipher.

You can use any part of the RGB info if your image is really in grayscale. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Here a little code to understand how work Processing with color arguments. I hope tha's can help you.

```
void setup() {
  colorMode(RGB,255,255,255,255);
  println("colorMode",g.colorModeX,g.colorModeY,g.colorModeZ,g.colorModeA);
  background(random(g.colorModeX),random(g.colorModeY),random(g.colorModeZ),random(g.colorModeA));
  int color_arg = get((int)random(width),(int)random(height));
  println("color_arg: ",color_arg);
  println("color_arg rgb_a:",red(color_arg),green(color_arg),blue(color_arg),alpha(color_arg));
  println("color_arg hsb_a:",hue(color_arg),saturation(color_arg),brightness(color_arg),alpha(color_arg));
}
```